# AmCharts serial chart date ordering issue

Tags: javascript, html, amcharts

I have 4 different data sets `data1, data2, data3, data4`, each data set contain different dates, so date is not in order, hence graph is not displaying according to date

Here is my code

```js
        AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
            "type": "serial",
            "addClassNames": true,
            "startDuration": 0.4,
            "theme": "light",
            "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
            "trendLines": [],
            "applyGapValue": 0,
            "graphs": [{
                "bullet": "round",
                "type": "smoothedLine",
                "valueField": "data2",
            }, {
                "bullet": "round",
                "type": "smoothedLine",
                "valueField": "data1",
            }, {
                "bullet": "round",
                "type": "smoothedLine",
                "valueField": "data3",
            }, {
                "bullet": "round",
                "type": "smoothedLine",
                "valueField": "data4",
            }],
            "guides": [],
            "valueAxes": [{
                "id": "ValueAxis-1",
            }],
            "categoryField": "date",
            "categoryAxis": {
                "parseDates": true,
                "equalSpacing": true,
                "minorGridEnabled": true,
                "gridPosition": "start",
            },
            "allLabels": [],
            "balloon": {
                "borderThickness": 3,
                "horizontalPadding": 17,
                "offsetX": 50,
                "offsetY": 8
            },
            "chartCursor": {
                "cursorAlpha": 0,
                "cursorPosition": "mouse",
                "graphBulletSize": 1,
                "zoomable": false
            },
            "legend": {
                "enabled": true,
                "useGraphSettings": true,
                "position": "top",
            },

            "dataProvider": [




                {
                    "date": "2017-06-02",
                    "data1": 202,
                }, {
                    "date": "2017-06-04",
                    "data1": 420,
                }, {
                    "date": "2017-06-05",
                    "data1": 910,
                }, {
                    "date": "2017-06-07",
                    "data1": 60,
                },


                {
                    "date": "2017-06-02",
                    "data2": 110,
                }, {
                    "date": "2017-06-04",
                    "data2": 920,
                }, {
                    "date": "2017-06-05",
                    "data2": 320,
                }, {
                    "date": "2017-06-07",
                    "data2": 355,
                },

                {
                    "date": "2017-06-02",
                    "data3": 80,
                }, {
                    "date": "2017-06-04",
                    "data3": 350,
                }, {
                    "date": "2017-06-05",
                    "data3": 710,
                }, {
                    "date": "2017-06-07",
                    "data3": 710,
                },
                {
                    "date": "2017-06-02",
                    "data4": 580,
                }, {
                    "date": "2017-06-04",
                    "data4": 510,
                }, {
                    "date": "2017-06-05",
                    "data4": 702,
                }, {
                    "date": "2017-05-07",
                    "data4": 940,
                }, {
                    "date": "2017-06-09",
                    "data4": 940,
                },
            ]
        });
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#chartdiv {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

in the output I want chart to be displayed according to ordered date, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you do have to sort the data by dates as previously mentioned, it's not enough for AmCharts. You also need to group the data by date as well or your chart will not render or behave correctly, i.e. the array element with the date "2017-06-02" needs to have the "data1", "data2", "data3", "data4" properties in the same element.

Here's one way to group it (assuming your data is in a variable called `chartData`):

```
var dataMap = {}; //map to group data by date
var newChartData = []; //new chart data array
chartData.forEach(function(dataItem) {
  if (!dataMap[dataItem.date]) {
    dataMap[dataItem.date] = {};
  }
  Object.keys(dataItem).forEach(function(key) { //assign keys to map
    if (key !== "date") {
      dataMap[dataItem.date][key] = dataItem[key];
      dataMap[dataItem.date].date = dataItem.date;
    }
  });
});

//sort the dates and add the grouped objects to the new array.
Object.keys(dataMap).sort(function(lhs, rhs) {
  return new Date(lhs) - new Date(rhs);
}).forEach(function(date) {
  newChartData.push(dataMap[date]);
});
```

Demo:

```js
var chartData = [
  {
    "date": "2017-06-02",
    "data1": 202,
  }, {
    "date": "2017-06-04",
    "data1": 420,
  }, {
    "date": "2017-06-05",
    "data1": 910,
  }, {
    "date": "2017-06-07",
    "data1": 60,
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-06-02",
    "data2": 110,
  }, {
    "date": "2017-06-04",
    "data2": 920,
  }, {
    "date": "2017-06-05",
    "data2": 320,
  }, {
    "date": "2017-06-07",
    "data2": 355,
  },

  {
    "date": "2017-06-02",
    "data3": 80,
  }, {
    "date": "2017-06-04",
    "data3": 350,
  }, {
    "date": "2017-06-05",
    "data3": 710,
  }, {
    "date": "2017-06-07",
    "data3": 710,
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-06-02",
    "data4": 580,
  }, {
    "date": "2017-06-04",
    "data4": 510,
  }, {
    "date": "2017-06-05",
    "data4": 702,
  }, {
    "date": "2017-05-07",
    "data4": 940,
  }, {
    "date": "2017-06-09",
    "data4": 940,
  },
];

var dataMap = {}; //map to group data by date
var newChartData = []; //new chart data array
chartData.forEach(function(dataItem) {
  if (!dataMap[dataItem.date]) {
    dataMap[dataItem.date] = {};
  }
  Object.keys(dataItem).forEach(function(key) { //assign keys to map
    if (key !== "date") {
      dataMap[dataItem.date][key] = dataItem[key];
      dataMap[dataItem.date].date = dataItem.date;
    }
  });
});

//sort the dates and add the grouped objects to the new array.
Object.keys(dataMap).sort(function(lhs, rhs) {
  return new Date(lhs) - new Date(rhs);
}).forEach(function(date) {
  newChartData.push(dataMap[date]);
});

AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "addClassNames": true,
  "startDuration": 0.4,
  "theme": "light",
  "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
  "trendLines": [],
  "applyGapValue": 0,
  "graphs": [{
    "bullet": "round",
    "type": "smoothedLine",
    "valueField": "data2",
  }, {
    "bullet": "round",
    "type": "smoothedLine",
    "valueField": "data1",
  }, {
    "bullet": "round",
    "type": "smoothedLine",
    "valueField": "data3",
  }, {
    "bullet": "round",
    "type": "smoothedLine",
    "valueField": "data4",
  }],
  "guides": [],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "id": "ValueAxis-1",
  }],
  "categoryField": "date",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "equalSpacing": true,
    "minorGridEnabled": true,
    "gridPosition": "start",
  },
  "allLabels": [],
  "balloon": {
    "borderThickness": 3,
    "horizontalPadding": 17,
    "offsetX": 50,
    "offsetY": 8
  },
  "chartCursor": {
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "cursorPosition": "mouse",
    "graphBulletSize": 1,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "legend": {
    "enabled": true,
    "useGraphSettings": true,
    "position": "top",
  },

  "dataProvider": newChartData
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the data like this:

```
chartData.sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
});
```

Let's say you do this before passing it to the dataProvider property.